# How to post python dataframe values to Postman in Json object and send the data to sever using flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, postman

Please tell the code to write dataframe having 2 columns in Json format in postman  and post to it server using flask request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your needed DataFrame with the data in the python console and either pickler it or convert it to json. I recommend the latter.

If you pickled it then send it as payload using postman and deserialize it on server side to DataFrame.

If you converted it to json then just use

```
pandas.read_json()
```

and get the json in DataFrame format.

Comment: Can we use pandas.read_json in postman?